# Rails: How to load images right after upload without new HTTP request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to create a site using RoR where you can upload pics and have them load on the bottom right after you upload them without going to a new page. Could someone guide me on how I would do this?

Would it be possible? Since uploading would require a form, which is more of a "new" controller action, while displaying the uploaded images are more of a "show" controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do that with ajax. Have a look at [this article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) on how to create remote forms in rails 3.

To show the image that was uploaded, you'd have to:

1. get rails to respond to the request (in say the create action) and return a json object with the link to the image that was just added
2. add some logic to the javascript response handler to append the image returned from rails to the page

To explain all the details of this would be a bit too much for one answer, but I think that's basically the skeleton of what you'd have to do.